# How do I add static html files to my Aegir install

Tags: .htaccess, aegir

I have Aegir install running on a rack space server. In addition to the Drupal sites I am running, I would also like to be able to create static websites and server them from the same server. What steps do I need to do to get this to work with Aegir.

I tried the following

1.create a new file within vhostd containing

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mysite
ServerName mysite.mydomain.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

1. add html file to var/www/vhosts/mysite
   3 restart apache ? (actually i'm not sure how to do this form aegir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static websites cannot be managed by Aegir, so you should setup them separately on your server.

If you really need to restart apache from Aegir interface, just run 'Verify' task for any of the websites installed (hostmaster will work too). On verify, Aegir runs 'apache2ctl graceful' which effectively restarts apache.